# What replaced get_sb_nodev and get_sb in latest Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, superblock

I'm wondering what function replaced [get_sb_nodev](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h?v=2.6.38#L1825) and get_sb function in Linux kernel ?

It's no longer available in 3.5+ kernel

Answer (score 1):

`get_sb` function used to appear in `struct file_system_type`, In latest Linux Kernel this is replace by a `mount` function

`struct dentry *(*mount) (struct file_system_type *, int, const char *, void *);`